# Combine three "complex" PHP conditions in one perfect php snippet

Tags: php, drupal, conditional-statements

I'm stuck in Drupal Panels / PHP Access plugins.

At least, now I found the three conditions to create my final snippet. the purpose of it is to return TRUE; if "condition1 is TRUE" OR "condition2 is TRUE" OR "condition3 is TRUE". I found a lot of similar questions, but the last condition force me to post here to find the right way to do this.

Condition 1:

```
// At least  $view1->result has result.
$view1 = views_get_view('sp_onglet_videos');
$view1->set_display('views-tab-embed_1');
$output1 = $view1->preview();
if ($view1->result) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Condition 2 (same thing):

```
// At least  $view2->result has result.
$view2 = views_get_view('sp_onglet_audio');
$view2->set_display('views-tab-default');
$output2 = $view2->preview();
if ($view2->result) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Condition 3 is more complex:

```
// Checks for content in the field field_txt_videos.
if (isset($contexts['argument_nid_1']->data-> field_txt_videos)) {
  $field = $contexts['argument_nid_1']->data-> field_txt_videos;
  if (is_null($field)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
  if (is_array($field)) {
    foreach ($field as $key => $val) {
      if (is_array($val)) {
        $field[$key] = array_filter($val);
      }
    }
    $field = array_filter($field);
    return count($field);
  }
  if (is_string($field) && trim($field) == '') {
    return FALSE;
  }
  if ($field) {
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

I would like to have something clean (and functional) like this:

```
if ($view1->result && $view2->result && $field) {
return TRUE;
      }
```

But it's to tricky for my php knowledge. Need a little help !

Answer (score 0):

You want to save the result of the 3rd condition (into a variable) and use this result to run your final condition/query. But you can query the 3rd condition if it is a function.

Comment: huh, yes something like this, but  i'm lost with all this "if", "return", etc. I'll try to find how to do this.

Comment: I corrected my answer. You should make a functiom out of the 3rd condition.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to properly space your code and use *plenty of newlines*.

However, PHP does have some pretty cool tricks to do assignment inside conditional statements.

```
if(($view1 = views_get_view('sp_onglet_videos')) AND $view1->set_display('views-tab-embed_1') AND ($output1 = $view1->preview()) AND $view1->result) return TRUE;
```

However, as you can see this code is a mess - don't do it unless your assignment is really small. Take this simple security check at the top of a PHP file:

```
<?php defined('BASE_PATH') OR die('Not Allowed');
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice Xeoncross, but I found the first condition here http://drupal.org/node/446798 . you structure does not output the same result, I think. I try to understand: for me the variables are declared before the if condition.

Comment: I don't want to test a path or a constant. It's the result of views, or DB queries, if you don't know drupal.

Comment: @elektrorl I just wanted to show you that you can also set variables inside conditions and have their values tested `if($value = hi()){...}`.

Comment: ha ok I'm learning web development in the wrong way, first Drupal and when I'm really stuck after a lot of modules usage, I have to learn PHP, I'm so stupid. thanks for the advice, and do you think it is possible to chain the three conditions here?

Comment: @elektrorl, why don't you stop by [videos.code2design.com](http://videos.code2design.com) and watch some of the PHP videos? There are also lots of other good PHP video sites out there that could save you some time if you can just spend a couple hours watching all them.